# How to find a image with transparent background on the screen?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, image-processing, pyautogui

So, I have an image with a transparent background and dimensions (`Width_1`, `High_1`), and what I'm trying to do is to find this image (but not necessary with the same dimension) on the screen let's say with dimensions (`Width_2`, `High_2`), so with that in mind I wrote this following code:

```
def resize_untill_find(image,bigger_or_smaller, min_size = 50 , max_size = 150 , one_match_per_point = 'on'): #(imagem, diminuir ou aumentar, min_size = reduce the image until min_size%, max_size = expand the image until max_size%)
    print('Press CTRL+ALT to start:')
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('control+alt'):
            break
    image_info = Ferramentas.get_image_first_info(image)# get width, high, and pixels number off the image
    image = cv2.imread(image)
    image_rate = image_info['whidth'] / image_info['high'] #proportion Width/High
    ocurrencies = {} # [x,y,w,h]
    match_number = 1 # number of the ocurrency
    high = image_info['high']
    if bigger_or_smaller == 'smaller':
        while int((high/image_info['high'])*100) >= int(min_size): # while the resize are not under min_size
            print('{}%'.format(round((high/image_info['high'])*100)))
            width = round(image_info['whidth']-((image_info['high'] - high) * image_rate))
            dimension = (width,high) # new dimension of the image
            print('Dimension:', dimension)
            image_resized = cv2.resize(image,dimension) #resize the image
                matches_position = pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen(image_resized, confidence = 0.9)
                for region in matches_position:
                    region = list(region)
                    ocurrencies['Match_{}'.format(match_number)] = region # region = [X,Y, new_Width , new_High]
                    match_number += 1 
            if one_match_per_point == 'on':
                match_position = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(image_resized, confidence = 0.9)
                if match_position != None:
                    match_position = list(match_position)
                    ocurrencies['Match_{}'.format(match_number)] = match_position # region = [X,Y, new_Width , new_High]
                    match_number += 1
            high -= 1
    if bigger_or_smaller == 'bigger':
        while int((high/image_info['high'])*100) <= int(max_size):
            print('{}%'.format(round((high/image_info['high'])*100)))
            width = round(image_info['whidth']+((high - image_info['high']) * image_rate))
            dimension = (width,high) # image new dimension
            print('Dimension:', dimension)
            image_resized = cv2.resize(image,dimension) #resize the imge with new dimensions
            if one_match_per_point == 'off':
                matches_position = pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen(image_resized, confidence = 0.9) # lista todos os matches 90% iguais ao da imagem redimensionada
                for region in matches_position:
                    region = list(region)
                    ocurrencies['Match_{}'.format(match_number)] = region # region = [X,Y, new_Width , new_High]
                    match_number += 1   
            if one_match_per_point == 'on':
                match_position = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(image_resized, confidence = 0.9)
                if match_position != None:
                    match_position = list(match_position)
                    ocurrencies['Match_{}'.format(match_number)] = match_position # region = [X,Y, new_Width , new_High]
                    match_number += 1 
            high += 1
    print(ocurrencies)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    return ocurrencies
```

I don't know if there is an better way to do this, if there is, please tell me I will be glad to improve the code (it must be as fast as possible), but the main problem is: **it can't match templates with transparency, and transparency gradient background**.

So I've this image:

[image: image with transparent background, and black gradient on the borders]

and the program can't find the image and get it coordinates.

***EDIT:**

So I'm able to take this image:

[image]
and resize until finding a match on this image here:

[image]

but when I try to take a .png picture with a transparent background it doesn't work:

[image] (template) and try to find a match on this one
[image](*screen1*) or this [image](*screen2*).

You can notice that the first template has the same dimensions as the *screen1* but has a dark-gray background, and the *screen2* has also a different background and is smaller (but maintains the original Width/High proportion) than the original.

So what I want is to be able to use the *template* to find the *screen1* or *screen2* in some place of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

```
def search(screen, img):
sx, sy = screen.size
ix, iy = img.size
for xstart in range(sx - ix): 
    for ystart in range(sy - iy):
        #search for the pixel on the screen that equals the pixel at img[0:0]
        if img.getpixel((0,0)) == screen.getpixel((xstart, ystart)):
            match = 1 #temporary
            for x in range(ix): #check if first row of img is on this coords
                if img.getpixel((x,0)) <> screen.getpixel((xstart+x, ystart)):
                    match = 0 #if there's any difference, exit the loop
                    break 
            if match == 1: #otherwise, if this coords matches the first row of img
                for x in range(ix): 
                    for y in range(iy):
                        #check every pixel of the img
                        if img.getpixel((x,y)) <> screen.getpixel((xstart+x, ystart+y)):
                            match = 0 #any difference - break
                            break
                if match == 1: return (xstart, ystart) #return top-left corner coordinates
return (-1,-1) #or this, if not found
#i found this somewhere else
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, is really faster than mine, but I still not able to find images, with different size and transparency, when I try it te code returns (-1,-1), I'll edit my post to bring more examples of the pictures that I can't find a match